# Does esbiothrin kill mosquitos?

Tags: entomology, pesticides

I recently made use of an [esbiothrin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bioallethrin) insecticide spray I [bought](http://www.riem.be/fr/produits/ti-tox-total-250ml-400ml) in Europe.

I've been using this product for a while now, with good results, I found it to be completely useless when used in Morocco.

Does it work to kill mosquitos?

Comment: I also wanted to know why does in work in Europe and not in Africa. That's what twisted me a bit.

Comment: It is approved by the WHO as a product against mosquitoes, but maybe you need a different or stronger product in some countries; either because there are more mosquitoes, or maybe because they are more resistent to certain products?